# Data Studio | "No Data" when setting date range

Tags: google-analytics, data-visualization, looker-studio

### Objective:

Build a line chart with a date range and a growing count trend.

#### Data Format

### |------Date -------|------Count---- |

|---YYYY/MM/DD--- |-------- 1 ------------ |

|--------------------------|-------- 0 ------------ |

|--------------------------|-------- 0 ------------ |

|---YYYY/MM/DD--- |-------- 1 ------------ |

|---YYYY/MM/DD--- |-------- 1 ------------ |

## The Problem

When I look at my data in a table chart I can clearly see my data. However, When I choose a custom date range via data filter or defining in the chart I always get "**No Data**". I have ensured my date data is mapped to YYYY/MM/DD.

### Question

What is causing this behaviour? By all logic there is data, I can see it when I remove the date range or set to auto date range but not when I use a specific date range.

> #### Note
>
> Not all entries will have a date. I thought this might be a problem so I added a filter to exclude data where there was a date. This did not solve the problem. you may ask when I have null rows; this is because there is more data I have but cannot show here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe what is happening is that I am using Date but some data rows won't have date which results in an error. Filtering seems to happen after the data is read which still results in an error.

Answer (score 2):

Not the "RIGHT" answer but the following workaround worked for me.

Create a new field and setting the formula to `TODATE(Date,'DEFAULT_DASH','%Y%m%d')` where `Date` is your original date field that is not working.

Then use this new field as your date dimension and date range will work for it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `TODATE(Date,'DEFAULT_DASH','%Y%m%d')` as was said here but it didn't work.

What ended up working was to delete all graphs and date range filters, delete the data source and recreate it and add `TODATE(Date,'DEFAULT_DASH','%Y%m%d')` as a new field at the moment of the source creation, then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it solves your problem but after painfully going through everything I found that in the Blend Edit screen, there was an option to set the field that is used for dates. Somehow that had been set to the wrong field and needed correcting.